# So many Romanian words seem to end in "u"

Tags: morphology, etymology, orthography, romanian

I have just learned that the suffix "escu" in a Romanian name means "son of."  But it seems that the "u" is a common ending in all Romanian words.  Does that one letter have a meaning?

Comment: The Romanian -*escu* is the equivalent of the French -*esque*, German -*isch*, and English -*ish*. Saying that it means *son of* (in Romanian) is as misleading as saying the same for all other suffixes mentioned above.

Comment: @Lucian - It may also be considered the equivalent of the Italian names ending in *-eschi* (Tedeschi, Brunelleschi).

Comment: @Lucian - You are right, `-escu` is just the result of adding the definite article `-l` to `-esc` (Romanian equivalent of French `-esque` etc), like in the adjectives `omenesc`=human, `dumnezeiesc`=divine, `trupesc`=bodily, `câinesc`=dog-like (corresponding to the adverbs `omenește`, `dumnezeiește` etc).  For phonetic and etymological reasons that article has the result of bringing up the lost `u`, as said [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ul#Etymology).

Answer (score 15):

I don't think that the -u has a particular meaning in Romanian, unless in Rumanian it works to signal a particular ending, such as the masculine ending, but there's no mention about this ending on the article for [Romanian grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_grammar#Gender). Rather, I'd say it's simply what "survived" from the Latin endings (e.g. **-us**, **-um**). I tried to look for some resources but didn't find much. In any case I think you could look at [The Romance Languages](http://alturl.com/sz3pb) by Martin Harris, or [The Romance Languages](http://alturl.com/28yss) by Rebecca Posner.

The suffix "[-escu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanians#Surnames)" in Rumanian's names comes from the [Latin "-iscus"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-esc).

In any case, Romanian is not the only one that still has this heritage: Sardinian and Sicilian are other two examples that clearly still possess these endings.

These three languages are the only ones that kept the endings in **-u**<sup>1</sup>, while other Romance languages had changes. For example, italian changed the endings to **-o**. Romance languages are more or less far from Latin. You can see a comparison with the verb to sing, in the [Proposed divisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages#Proposed_divisions) section on the wikipedia article for [Romance Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages).

Let's see a comparison for the verb "**to enter**":

```
╔═══╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║   ║  Latin   ║ Italian  ║ Sardinian ║ Romanian ║ English   ║
║   ║ Intrare  ║ Entrare  ║ Intrare   ║ A intra  ║ To Enter  ║
╠═══╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1 ║ intro    ║ entro    ║ intro     ║ intru    ║ enter     ║
║ 2 ║ intras   ║ entri    ║ intrasa   ║ intri    ║ enter     ║
║ 3 ║ intrat   ║ entra    ║ intrata   ║ intră    ║ enters    ║
║ 4 ║ intramus ║ entriamo ║ intramusu ║ intrăm   ║ enter     ║
║ 5 ║ intratis ║ entrate  ║ intradese ║ intrați  ║ enter     ║
║ 6 ║ intrant  ║ entrano  ║ intrana   ║ intră    ║ enter     ║
╚═══╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

<sup>1: see comments. Also other Romance languages possess this ending but not orthographically, just phonetically.</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be as comprehensive as possible, but didn't find much information. I wanted to back up what I know from my experience, but there isn't much out there. Hope to find something in the future. If someone wants to fix or let me know possible mistakes, please do!

Comment: Portuguese and Occitan also have endings in /u/ but this is not orthographically indicated. E.g Pt "entro" /ẽtɾu/; Occ (Alpine-Provencal) "intro" /intru/

Comment: @MarkBeadles Oh! I didn't know that. Do you mind if I include it?

Comment: By the way - nice job on the table format.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I used [this tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html). It looks better there, though. I have to use the Code here and so it comes out with those spaces. :)

Comment: Portuguese paradigm is nearly identical to Spanish orthographically entro/entras/entra/entramos/entrais/entram but pronunciation is ẽtɾu/ẽtɾɐʃ/ẽtɾɐ/ẽtɾamuʃ/ẽtɾɐiʃ/ẽtɾɐ̃ũ/ with u phonemes (nasal and oral) in 1sg/1pl/3pl

Comment: Your example is about a verb. How about nouns?

Comment: @LouisRhys I don't have a lot of time at the moment. I'll address your comment as soon as possible. :)

Comment: Asturian also preserves the "-u" ending, lone among Iberio-Romance languages, as shown in its self-name: "Asturianu". It also preserves a form of neuter vs. most other Romance which now have just masculine/feminine.

Comment: Word-final -u did not actually survive in Romanian in most contexts. Word-final high vowels (-i, -u) reduced unless needed for consonant cluster support ("nostru", "albastru") (Alkire, Rosen 2010: sec. 10.1.8). Of course, there are exceptions, such as with proper names.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_grammar#Definite_article), **ul** is the definite article for (many) masculine and neuter nouns. E.g. cal-->calul i.e. horse-->the horse.
Commonly and informally, *ul* is reduced to *u*.

Comment: I think the OP was talking about vocabulary and orthography whereas this answer is specifically about pronunciation. I'm still voting it up though because the original question was too brief and thus allows this as a good answer.

Comment: Commonly and informally in speaking and writing, though yes, more common in speaking

Comment: @hippietrail - considering pronunciation is the only way of making sense of the question, otherwise the question would have been why so many words end in "L".

Comment: That definite article is not  always `ul`, but also  just `l`. One could say that the essential form is `l`, because `u` is added only when the noun ends with a consonant (because the musicality of the language, the facility of pronunciation demands it). On the other hand, as most such nouns do end in a consonant, the `ul` article is the most frequent.

Comment: *ul* is reduced to *u* not only commonly and informally, but because otherwise it would sound wrong. Because this fact is not clearly enunciated as a rule in school, the written language induced people to start pronouncing more and more the final `L`, but even so the normal speech tends to de-emphasize `L` in favor of `U` as much as possible.

Comment: In fact Romanian has many nouns that end in `u` (ou, bou, leu, râu, fiu,grâu, lucru), which get the `-l` article, while the ones ending in a consonant get the `-ul` article. I tend to think that structurally only one article it's at play here: either `-ul` is the real one, which simply loses the `u` in contact with u-ending nouns (to avoid double-u), or  `-l` is, which gets a `u` to avoid consonant+l ending.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of French, most Romance languages have a lot of masculine singular nouns ending in `o` and `u`. That feature is very striking and catches the ear at first contact. I think this is obvious in Italian and Spanish with `o` and in Portuguese and other languages (Neapolitan, Sicilian, Catalan, Sardinian, Corsican, Asturian) with `u`.

In Romanian also there are singular masculine and neuter nouns which end with `u` (*ou, bou, leu, râu, fiu, brâu, frâu, grâu, flăcău, căpăstru, lucru, curcubeu, austru, suflu, Dumnezeu*, including a series of words ending in augmentative *-andru*: *puiandru, băiețandru, copilandru, cățelandru, flăcăiandru, măcăleandru* etc) - as well as with other vocals -, but the great majority end with a consonant

But when the latter get their Barkanische-Sprachbund-specific post-fixed article, the Romance-style `u` reappears. As in normal speech the `l` is barely pronounced, much more nouns seem to end in `u` after all.

As said [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ul#Etymology):

> *-ul* is a variant of *-l* with the original *u* (lost in most modern Romanian nouns) reappearing at the end of the noun it is attached to
> as a link to the definite article to make pronunciation smoother. For
> example, in its evolution from Latin, the word *foc* probably passed
> through a phase in early Romanian where it was **focu*, but the *u*
> only appears now as a part of the definite form, *focul* (with the
> definite article suffix *-l*), corresponding to Vulgar Latin **focu
> illu*. The grammatical rule was generalized and also came to apply to
> nouns of non-Latin origin after they became part of Romanian (e.g.
> *război → războiul*).

or in the *Gramatica limbii române. Vol.1. Cuvântul* (Grammar of Romanian Language, Volume 1. The Word) of the Romanian academy, page 98:

> In contemporary language `-l` is not pronounced anymore in current
> speech, its function being fulfilled by the preceding vowel `-u`. This
> use is accepted in standard spoken language.

***The noun-end in `u` is as such a normal feature in Romanian as well as in a large part of Romance languages.*** (In Aromanian the corresponding article is `-lu`, which follows this trend.)